# Refrescar solo una parte de la página con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Quiero hacer que se refresque una sola parte de la Web, tengo HTML que es el bloque que deseo actualizar:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Hora de entrada</th>
            <th>Tiempo restante</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>José Fernández</td>
           <td>8:00</td>
           <td>05:00</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>   
</table>
```

Y el siguiente JQuery, que está mal hecho, pero no sé como lograrlo:

```
<script>
  function refrescar(tiempo){
    setTimeout($("#table"), tiempo);
  }
  refrescar(10000);
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Por refrescar debo entender ajustar el tiempo restante? Si es así ¿Cual es el límite de tiempo? y ¿Qué debe ocurrir cuando se agote?

Comment: No, eso es otra cosa (También lo debo hacer), me refieo a actualizar el bloque de código, para no actualizar la página entera. Con esta línea me actualiza todo la página: `setTimeout("location.reload(true);", tiempo);` pero deseo solamente actualizar la `tabla`

Comment: Es que si sólo necesitas actualizar el tiempo hasta que alcance un valor no necesitas recargar la página durante ese "proceso" de actualizaciones. Y, sólo cuando alcance el límite necesitarías disparar la acción de vencimiento. `"location.reload(true);"` sobra debes actualizar el valor y con un script sencillo puedes

Comment: No, aquí no necesito actualizar el tiempo sino la página cuando se cumplan el tiempo, en el ejemplo dice `10000` que equivale a `10` segundos, cada `10` segundos actualiza la página, pero en este caso no quiero que sea la página entera sino el bloque de código, uso `#table` para indicarle cual bloque se debe actualizar.

Comment: Pero, actualizar esa tabla equivale a hacer ajuste a una celda ya que ni el usuario, ni la hora en que inició cambian. En consecuencia  necesitas restar 10 segundos al tiempo restante, y para hacer eso **es innecesario recargar la página**. Otra cosa será actuar cuando se haya agotado el tiempo.

Comment: En el controlador yo decido si se lista en los resultados o no esa información, lo que quiero es que cuando se venza el tiemp0o actualizar la página para que no se muestren los que ya vencieron

Comment: En ese caso consulta [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) está en español. Y, asigna un id a la tabla para reemplazarla usando `$('#idtabla').load(url)` Borré la respuesta que te estaba preparando por no ser pertinente.

Comment: gracias, ya reviso!